# Does didSelectRowAtIndexPath overwrite storyboard segues?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to setup a segue so on some cells, it goes to the next view via segue, but on other cells, it follows the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

If I set didSelectRowAtIndexPath, would that cause the segue to stop working?

How do I specify which rows should use segue and which should not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both `didSelect` and segues are executed.

Use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to determine whether to use the segue or not.